# Sed search and replace in every line in file, first raw

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk, sed

i'm trying to develop a shell script which scan a csv file (example below) and replace the EPOCH time stamp with the a readable time stamp.

the csv file looks like (column is EPOCH) :

```
1464007935578, 852111
1464007935600, 852111
1464007935603, 852111
1464007935603, 1900681
```

**my script code:**

```
#!/bin/bash

file=xxx.csv
while read line; do
    epoch=`echo $line | awk -F',' '{print $1}'`
    miliSec=$(($epoch % 1000 ))
    timeWithoutMiliSec=`echo "$(date +"%T" -d@$(($epoch / 1000)))"`
    fullTime=`echo "$timeWithoutMiliSec,$miliSec"`
    echo $line | awk -F',' '{print $1}'|sed -i 's/[0-9]*/'$fullTime'/g' $file
done <$file
```

**Desired output**

```
12:52:15,255 852111
12:52:15,257 852111
12:52:15,259 852111
12:52:15,261 1900681
```

but when i run script it stuck and create many files start with sed*
and i must kill the script in order to stop it.
i think that the problem might be with the while loop combining with the sed while both (sed and while) take argument $file

can someone please advise about that issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: the $file at the end of the `echo .. sed ... ` line seems to be superfluous?

Comment: @StefanHegny it is not superfluous because OP wants to use `sed -i`. However, it is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk`'s [`strftime()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) function:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '{print strftime("%F", $1/1000), $2}' file
2016-05-23, 852111
2016-05-23, 852111
2016-05-23, 852111
2016-05-23, 1900681
```

This uses

> **%F**
>
> Equivalent to specifying ‘%Y-%m-%d’. This is the ISO 8601 date format.

Note I have to divide by 1000 because you have the miliseconds in your input.

Comment: it seems that OP just want `time,ms`.  You can adjust the output a bit.

Comment: @Kent it is a bit confusing what the OP wants, so I will wait a bit until s/he provides feedback about the format. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Thanks everyone.
my desire output is: 
`12:52:15,253  196751\n
12:52:15,255  196755`

Comment: @Assafbaruch where does `,253 196751` come from? Again: edit your question with a proper [mcve].

Comment: 253 are the milliseconds and the other integer right after is an ID, should leave as is.

Comment: @Assafbaruch this doesn't make any sense. In your sample input there are no `196751`.

Comment: input example: 1464007935603, 1900681
the left decimal number is the epoch time which need to be converted to readable time include milliseconds: HH:SS:MM,mmm and the right decimal number is just and ID and should be no changed at all. leave as is.

Comment: @Assafbaruch you posted a bunch of code to do something, let's call it X. The code is overkilling, so I suggest you to use `awk`, because a simple call to it can handle all those lines are doing. However, for your specific input / output you need to give a proper explanation, and comments are not the place.

Comment: @Assafbaruch your unix time is `1464007935578`. This means you also have milliseconds in it; however, you say that the milliseconds has to be 255. Where does this 255 come from? If I say `date -d@1464007935 "+%T"` I get `14:52:15`. The three trailing digits should remain as is, so I cannot figure out why they become 255.

Comment: if you convert epoch time `1464007935578` with date you will get `12:52:15` and the milliseconds in that case are 578. so finally, in that case, i would like to replace the epoch `1464007935578` with `12:52:15.578`

Comment: @Assafbaruch `awk -F, '{printf "%s,%.3d %d\n", strftime("%T", $1/1000), $1%100, $2}' file` should make it.